# What is the fundamental theorem on discrete groups of Euclidean spaces?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, euclidean-geometry, discrete-geometry

I have been reading the book *Using Algebraic Geometry* by David A. Cox, John Little, Donal O'Shea for a university project. I am not clear as to what exactly in meant by the phrase "the fundamental theorem on discrete groups of Euclidean spaces" on page 334, shown below.

[image: COx-Little-Shea]

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot of part of the page here: http://s3.postimg.org/wsrp1qctf/image.png

Answer (score 0):

The result named "fundamental theorem" should be the following:

*Proposition:* A subgroup $S$ of a Euclidean vector space $V$ is a lattice if and only if $S$ is discrete.

Here a lattice means a subgroup of the form
$$
S=\mathbb{Z}w_1\oplus \cdots \oplus \mathbb{Z}w_n
$$
with linear independent vectors $w_i\in V$.

Comment: So would it make sense for me to say: As a subgroup of a Euclidean vector space is a lattice if and only if it is discrete, a basis $w_{}1,...,w_{n-1}\in v_{F}^{\perp}\cap\mathbb{R}^{n}$ can be chosen such that every element of $v_{F}^{\perp}\cap\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a linear combination of the $w_{1},...,w_{n-1}$ with integer coefficients.

Comment: Yes, this follows from the "fundamental theorem" with $S=\nu_F^{\perp}\subset \mathbb{R}^n$.